# How to embed java code in HTML or Javascript

Tags: java, html

I've done a bit of research but nothing seems to explain how to embed a java code into an html easily, considering I know close to nothing about html and javascript.  Essentially I made a pretty cool java code that can operate any amount of values of any base system together and output the result in whatever base you want.  I've seen some stuff about applets and .jar files but I don't really know what those are or how to use them. My java code name is BaseCalc5.java with class BaseCalc5.class.  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?? HTML is intended to be consumed by the browser. The browser cannot understand java. It can only understand JavaScript. What are you trying to solve by `embedind a java code into an html` file?

Comment: You usually don't do that. The Java code runs on a server, and you access that code in the form of service(s), by sending some input data, and most of the times expecting some result(s) back. If you insist on embedding, take a look at (already deprecated in recent JVM versions) Applets. Another alternative is just to migrate your Java code into JavaScript...might be easy.

Comment: @codeMan , I kind of just want to improve the GUI for the code so it looks a bit better.  I really don't know the best way to go about this. Looking for any advice.

Comment: You'll have to understand how web pages work and may be you can do the same using javascript.